# Streaming from a uPnP server to another computer over LAN

Tags: streaming, lan

I set up MediaTomb on my ubuntu 9.10 computer and it streams to our ps3 perfectly. Now I am wondering what the easiest way to stream it to other desktops/laptops over our home network?

Answer (score 2):

MediaTomb is a [UPnP AV MeidaServer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP_AV_MediaServers).  Any player that supports the UPnP standard and the video types that you are serving should be able to play them over your home network.  Wikipedia has a list of [UPnP AV clients(AKA control points)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP_AV_MediaServers#UPnP_AV_clients_.28ControlPoint.29).  A few include:

- [Windows Media Player 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player_11)
- [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) with the [foo_UPnP plugin](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=69664).
- [Rythmbox](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/)

Comment: The first thing I thought of to use was Windows Media Player 11 on a windows 7 laptop and that connects ok but does not find any media on the device even though I have some movies that will stream correctly on the ps3. Any tips on how to get windows to find the media?